# How is the discrete convolution applied to real world signals

Tags: signal-processing, convolution

I'm in a position where I need to practically apply a filter to digitally sampled input data in realtime (from an ADC or otherwise). In other words, a [Discrete Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution). However, after reviewing the literature, it struck me that this operation requires predicting the future sample points of the input function.

The discrete convolution of an input function and some filter of length `(2M+1)` is defined as

[image]

Of course this implies, for instance, that

```
(f*g)[0] = f[M]g[-M] + f[M-1]g[-M+1] + ...
```

That is, the first output index of the convolution is a function of some M future data points of the input function.

In practice how is this done in *realtime* as data samples are captured by some source? At a glance I can only square this by the operation inherently producing a *delay* in the output `(f*g)[n]` of length `(2M + 1)`, or the size of the filter function `g[n]`.

This being a direct result of the dependency that the convolution not being applied to
the input signal prior to first sampling sufficient data points such that the summation over all points `[-M,M]` can be applied.

Of course I think this is incorrect, but *practically* I remain unsure.

Comment: Time for a paradigm shift.  You will be working in the "very recent" past.  There will always be lags when performing signal processing to process (or detect) something.  The key is minimizing the lag.  Digital data is acquired through ADCs.  A driver accumulates them into buffers to be processed.  When you are designing this type of code, you are given constraints as to how fast you need to report your results (no one wants day old detections).  The filtering and correlating will add some lag, but expect the key lag drivers to be the overall buffer transfer scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, applying a filter in real time produces a delay.

A *linear phase* filter delays all frequencies by the same amount.  These filters are always symmetric FIR filters, and imply a delay of half the filter length.

Other kinds of filters delay different frequencies by different amounts, and may even have bands with negative delay, but they will have a delaying effect overall.